# 'Launch Failed. Binary Not Found' error when trying to run program

Tags: compiler-errors

I'm new to using C++ for programming and I have no idea what this error means or how to solve it. Every other forum on this specific error gives different remedies, but none of them have worked for me. Can someone help me to understand what this means?

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
std::cout << "Game Over!" << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

It should be a pretty straight forward 'HelloWorld'-esque program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means your IDE can't find the compiled binary file to execute.

Make sure you are actually building the project and check if the binary exists.

Comment: Yeah building ended up working. I had tried that but I think I had an issue with having the right panel selected or something when I hit build. Like I said, I'm new to this and am a lot more familiar with Java which didn't require this sort of thing, at least not as explicitly. :P Thanks for the help!